# Hiding plot values

Tags: pine-script

Considering this example script

```
//@version=4
study("PlayGround", shorttitle="PG", overlay=true)

l = low
h = high
c = close

plotLow     = true
plotHigh    = true
plotClose   = false

plot(plotLow   ? l : na, color=color.red)
plot(plotHigh  ? h : na, color=color.green)
plot(plotClose ? c : na, color=color.blue)
```

Which shows the values `PG 705.99 705.99 n/a` in the top-left corner.
The `n/a` is showing because `plotClose = false`.

[image: Example]

I would like to hide the `n/a` values for plots that are 'hidden'.
Is that possible in Pine Script?

Answer (score 1):

It's not currently possible. Using the new `display = display.none` with `plot()` should do that, but it currently doesn't. This should be fixed in the future.