# use display.all only if timeframe display.none

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

Hi guy's im trying to not get error using this lines

```
HERE = if timeframe.period=='D'
    display=display.all
else
    display=display.none

EMA= ema(close,20)

plot(EMA,color=color.red,HERE) //or
plot(timeframe.period=='D'?EMA:na,color=color.red,HERE)
```

the intention is to draw the EMA only in a specific timeframe so that when the timeframe is changed the n/a is removed in the values next to

```
study("My script")
```

displayed in main chart

Answer (score 0):

Would the below achieve what you are after?

```
//@version=4
study("Daily EMA Only", overlay=true)

TF_D = (timeframe.period =="D")

EMA= ema(close,20)

plot(EMA and TF_D ? EMA : na, color=color.red)
```

Please have a read of the below link:

[Pine Script: Is there a way to hide specific indicator values from the data window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63418248/pine-script-is-there-a-way-to-hide-specific-indicator-values-from-the-data-wind)

[Hiding plot values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61557582/hiding-plot-values)

Comment: not because, the values displayed next to the indicator´s name, in week for eg, will show the legend "n/a"...and if de const integer display.none is used, the indicator will apear turn off. The const interger display.none made the style checkbox not activated

Comment: https://ibb.co/Q9hTySf
https://ibb.co/7CtndNm
https://ibb.co/SdhWrpL

Comment: Having read through other questions on here (provided links above) it doesn't look like what you are trying to achieve can be achieved at this moment.